# Unable to get property 'value' in Telerik.Web.UI.RadInputExtender.prototype.isEmpty

Tags: asp.net, telerik, webresource.axd

I received the following error , it triggered trough `Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd` during processing submit event, so I don't know which component causes the problem.

In `Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd` at line 31126

`if(!(a.value&&a.value.replace(/ /g,""))){return true;`

It gives errors saying:

> Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference

​Well I understand the `a` is null, but to which `telerik` or `ui` item is it referring?

**The Call Stack is:**

```
Telerik.Web.UI.RadInputExtender.prototype.isEmpty [Line: 31126, Col: 1], Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd
Telerik.Web.UI.RadInputExtender.prototype.get_value [Line: 31132, Col: 7], Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd
Telerik.Web.UI.RadInputExtender.prototype._beforeSubmit [Line: 31248, Col: 1], Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd
Telerik.Web.UI.RadInputManager.prototype._beforeSubmit [Line: 31311, Col: 6], Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd
Telerik.Web.UI.RadInputManager.prototype._onSubmit [Line: 31307, Col: 58], Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd
Telerik.Web.UI.RadInputManager.WebForm_OnSubmit [Line: 31322, Col: 56], Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd
onsubmit [Line: 21, Col: 90], ManualInvoiceEdit2.aspx
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.prototype._onFormSubmit [Line: 15, Col: 22512], Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.prototype._doPostBack [Line: 15, Col: 15349], Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.prototype._doPostBackWithOptions [Line: 15, Col: 16021], Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd
Anonymous function [Line: 6, Col: 298], Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd
Global code [Line: 1, Col: 1], script block (423)
```

I have

`Telerik.Web.UI.dll 2016.2.504.40`

`Telerik.Web.UI.Skins.dll 2016.2.504.40`

`jQuery 1.11.1`
​
I have tried in `MSIE 9, 10, 11`, `Firefox` and `chrome` versions published in last 5 years, it always gives the error.

Any help or comment?

Comment: It comes from a RadInput Control, try disable ajax (AjaxManager), what error do you recive now ?

Comment: Same thing in the Telerik forums, contains debugging ideas: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/unable-to-get-property-'value'-in-telerik-web-ui-radinputextender-prototype-isempty